# How to output from a txt file in C++. The file has one two rows

Tags: c++, file, fstream

The rows are as in the example:

```
583-4-153-15601-4  '\t' Time Warp Trio  '\t'  Scieszka Jon    '\t' 50  '\t'  50
583-0-133-15601-2  '\t'  Djemte e rruges pal    '\t'    Ardit Zotaj '\t' 50  '\t'  50
```

So Every string is separated by a tab. Basically it contains the information for a book.

```
ISBN-TITLE-AUTHOR-PRICE-NO. OF COPIES.<
//583-4-153-15601-4  '\t' Time Warp Trio  '\t'  Scieszka Jon    '\t' 50  '\t'  50
//583-0-133-15601-2  '\t'  Djemte e rruges pal    '\t'  Ardit Zotaj '\t' 50  '\t'  50
```

I have done this work so far but it doesn't give the right output me in the cmd.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("bookdata.txt");
    string line;
    string isbn, title, author;
    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 2;

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, isbn, '\t');
        getline(fin, title, '\t');
        getline(fin, author, '\t');
        fin >> var1;
        fin >> var2;
    }

    cout << isbn << title << author << endl;
    fin.close();
    cout << var1 << var2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: simply i want just to show the rows as they are in the text file.

Comment: Why does it have to be `!fin.eof()` every time, why??? `std::getline` returns the stream, which is implicitly convertible to `bool`, you could AND them together... If you could say more about the output, other than "it's right/wrong" that would be great.

Comment: @LogicStuff the output it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @LogicStuff idk why is (!fin.eof()) that's what they taught us in school

Comment: @ArditZotaj : No book that I've ever seen teaches or encourages `while (!fin.eof())`. The reason? It's wrong!

Comment: @ildjarn we don't have any book. We use the translation of english books. And the teachers are not so good in english. We don't have PC in the class. We have a blackboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
while (getline(fin, isbn, '\t') && getline(fin, title, '\t') &&
       getline(fin, author, '\t') && fin >> var1 && fin >> var2 &&
       fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'))
{
    cout << isbn << title << author << " " << var1 << " " << var2 << endl;
}
```

I used `fin.ignore`, so that we don't get `\n`, which is still in the stream after `fin >> var2`, as the first character of the next `isbn`. It could be also `fin.ignore(1, '\n')`...

You also have to print these variables in the loop, otherwise you'll just print the information of the last row in the file.

I also noticed, that you have `string line;` lying around. Another approach, now utilizing this object can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line).

Comment: it doesn't show anything. Just as before. Just a blank cmd. I tried also your suggestions. Just a blank cmd

Comment: @Ardit Check, if the file was open, then.

Comment: Nope, nothing. The same blank cmd.

Comment: @Ardit I expected you to tell me what `fin.is_open()` returned.

Comment: Now it's ok. The editor wasn't warking right. Thanks. So how do i show the second row as well?

Comment: It's ok dude. thank's. i figure it out how to show the second row as well. thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad it works... What was the problem with the second row?

Comment: well the <code> fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'))</code>

I removed it. So my next question. Is how to get this data in a vector. I am using a structure as well for the books:

struct Book
{
string isbn, title, author;
int price, copies};

Comment: There's many duplicates on that question, you'll want to make a `struct` or a `class` containing these attributes, and then make a `std::vector` of this class... Don't ask it, rather search for it.